# Select column names of a df using a regex, then store the outcome in a list of lists

Tags: r, regex, list

A toy `df`:

```
df <- data.frame("Q10/male" = c(1, 2),
                 "Q10/female" = c(3, 4),
                 "Age" = c(26, 39),
                 "Q11education" = c('low', 'high'),
                 "Q203/option_a" = c('yes', 'no'),
                 "Q203/option_b" = c('no', 'no'),
                 "Q203/option_c" = c('red', 'blue'),
                 check.names = FALSE
                 )
```

I want to select column names that start with a 'Q', followed by 2 or 3 digits, followed by a slash, and store them in an object. I do:

```
selected <- df %>% 
  select(matches('Q[0-9]{2,3}/')) %>% 
  names()
```

The object `selected` correctly returns:

```
[1] "Q10/male"      "Q10/female"    "Q203/option_a" "Q203/option_b" "Q203/option_c"
```

OK. Now I would want to create a list of lists, where each list contains the column names grouped by question number. That is, within a new list, I would like to have two lists, with the first list containing "Q10/male" and "Q10/female", and the second list containing "Q203/option_a", "Q203/option_b", and "Q203/option_c".

Desired output:

```
[[1]]
 [1] "Q10/male"                         
 [2] "Q10/female"            
                                           
[[2]]
[1] "Q203/option_a"                                                                                                     
[2] "Q203/option_b"
[3] "Q203/option_c"
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to do that in the same pipe.

How do we do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `split` you could do:

```r
split(selected, gsub("^(Q\\d+).*$", "\\1", selected))
#> $Q10
#> [1] "Q10/male"   "Q10/female"
#> 
#> $Q203
#> [1] "Q203/option_a" "Q203/option_b" "Q203/option_c"
```

Comment: Amazing, stefan. May I ask a naive question. Say I save the result of this in a new object, of what type will this new object be? A list of lists?

Comment: It's a `list` of character `vector`s if you do `questions <- split(...)`